# Running a local port scan and found open ports but, don't know what they're used for?

Tags: networking, security, ip, tcp, nmap

I wrote a very basic python script to port scan my system.  I'm running linux-mint lisa:

```
open_ports = []
for port in xrange(65536):
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        conn.connect(('localhost', port))
        open_ports.append(port)
        conn.close()
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

I returned a list of 7 ports and I ran netstat on each one:

```
sudo netstat -anlp | grep :(each port here)
```

I found that the first four were for `cups, mysql, polipo, and tor` but, the last three  `[44269, 46284, 47650]` were much higher numbers and I didn't get anything back.  I ran the script a few times more after this but, I would only return the first four.

Any ideas what they could be and what they're being used for?

Comment: Outbound traffic is normally sent with the higher ports. your port scan happened while tcp/udp sessions was in progress and ended before the sequential `netstat`s

Comment: This is most likely the case.  Thanks for clearing that up.  Why not make a formal answer?

Comment: wasn't sure if someone could give a even better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outbound traffic is normally sent with the higher ports. Your port scan happened while a tcp/udp session was in progress and ended before the sequential `netstat`s

Comment: But outbound traffic would not have tripped his port scanner, since it is trying to connect to a listening port, not an outbound port.